# Configurar DataSource JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Estoy configurando una conexión Java-SQLServer y a la hora de crear el datasource(la correré en un [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss)), tengo un par de dudas, ya que tengo ejemplos, pero solo para [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) y [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) Database.

Lo que tengo está tal que así:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/AppDS" poolname="/AppDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url></connection-url>
        <driver-class></driver-class>
        <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pwd</password>
        </security>
</datasource>
```

Me faltan esos dos campos `driver-class` y `driver`, no he encontrado documentación sobre como configurar el datasource de está manera.

Necesitaría saber que poner en esos dos sitios o un enlace que explicara la configuración con sqlserver.

Comment: Creo que el driver-class debe ser *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver*. Te paso un link de ayuda http://herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-Microsoft-JDBC-Driver.html

Comment: Esos dos valores dependen del driver que quieras usar, así que lo habitual es buscarlos en la página del proveedor del driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para `<connection-url>`

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Para `driver-class`

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

[Fuente](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-via-jdbc)

Comment: Ya levanté el servidor y conecta bien, muchísimas gracias.